# I am trying to insert data to tables using put command in happybase but getting below error

Tags: hbase, happybase

[image]

[image]

I am trying to insert data to tables using put command in happybase but getting below error.

Answer (score 0):

Your table listing says that you have two tables: 'employes' and 'mttable' but later you are trying `con.table('mytable')`. Are you just not spelling properly?